# Azure Durable Functions - Unable to change Task Hub Name to support Side-by-Side versioning

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm looking into implementing the Side-By-Side Azure Durable Functions versioning pattern described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-versioning

I have a FunctionApp deployed that currently uses the default `HubName` `DurableFunctionsHub`. I've read through the documentation above and it seems that all I am required to do is provided the following json in the host.json file:

```
{ 
   "version":"2.0",
   "durableTask": {
         "HubName": "TaskHubV1"
   }
}
```

When I deploy the new host.json file I can see in the portal that the host.json file has the changes above, but the storage container does not contain new Blobs, Queues or Tables prefixed with the `HubName` `TaskHubV1`. The Screenshot shows the storage container contents:

[Durable Function Storage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIQMD.png)
I was expecting additional Blobs, Queues and Tables to have been created using the `HubName` above as a prefix e.g.
Table Storage: `TaskHubV1History` `TaskHubV1Instance`

Could it be that `HubName` changes are not currently supported by V2 Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatting for V2 has the "durableTask" property under "extensions". Could you try,

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "HubName": "TaskHubV1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you :-).